# Redundant Function Call for Decorators in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, decorator, python-decorators

So I was looking at a certain class which has the following property function. However, the property method itself doesn't describe the procedure but instead calls another function to do so as follows:

```py
class Foo():

 @property
 def params(self):
     return self._params()

 @property
 def target(self):
     return self._target()

 def _params(self):
     return print("hello")
 def _target(self):
     return print("world")
```

What I am trying to understand if it is some sort of pattern? I have seen a similar thing in another class as well where the method with property decorator simply calls another method of same name with underscore in the beginning. 
Note: I do know what is property decorator but don't understand why this specific way of underscoring aims to achieve.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work

Comment: @hazirovich im not sure you understood the question well.

Comment: I sometimes uses that if for example `_params` takes a few parameters. I would call it `params` and the property would be a shortcut to the default arguments call.

Comment: @CedricH. What is the reason for doing so why not simply use params instead of creating another function _params as params is already declared as a property?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Something like this : create a function `get_information` with parameters with default values, then create a property `information` which calls `get_information` with the default set of parameters. This way users of the class have a shortcut and a better look and feel in some cases. In your specific case, has `_params` and `_target` do not take parameters, I do not see the point.

Comment: @CedricH.Please elaborate I didnt understand how users of the class have a shortcut and better look and feel. Assuming _params and _target take parameters, how shall it be a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, the property is being used as a shortcut for calling a method with a fixed set of arguments. As a slightly different example, consider

```
class Foo():

    @property
    def params(self):
        return self._params(1, "foo", True)

    def _params(self, x, y, z):
        ...

f = Foo()
```

Now, `f.params` is a shortcut for `f._params(1, "foo", True)`. Whether that is worth doing depends on whether `_params` is used for anything *other* than implementing the body of the `params` getter. If it isn't, there's little real point in writing code like this.

Comment: I kinda got it so essentially instead of writing ```f._params(1, "foo", True)``` we can simply do a shortcut such as ```f.params``` without having to specify additional arguments. Right?

Comment: Also could you please elaborate this: **```_params``` is used for anything other than implementing the body of the params getter**

Comment: If the sole purpose of defining `_params` is so that you can call it once from the body of `params`, then you should probably just put its code in `params` directly and not define `_params` in the first place. That would save an unnecessary function call.